# If $y = 3^{x}\arcsin(x)$ prove that $(1 - x^2)y'' - xy' = 0$

Tags: derivatives, solution-verification, exponential-function, partial-derivative, inverse-function

If $y = 3^{x}\arcsin(x)$ prove that $(1 - x^2)y'' - xy' = 0$

Our professor got this question into two examination cycles and this could be his third, YET no matter how much i try this just doesn't work?? If someone can enlighten me I'd be more than grateful.

(Sorry if the format of the question is weird, I haven't used this website before so I am unfamiliar with how it works)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Could you tell us where did you get stuck? Otherwise we cannot properly help you.

Comment: It's not true. It would be fine if $y = \arcsin x$ instead. The DE is not hard to solve anyway, as it is a separable DE in terms of $y'$.

Comment: OK, I'll bite. How do we get the factors of $\ln 3$ to cancel out? $3$ is next to $e$ on my keyboard and I suspect they meant $e^x\arcsin x$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi I thought the same thing, but it seems not. The general solution literally is just $C\arcsin(x) + D$. Exponentials don't enter into it.

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia I can find y' and y" thought they come out very odd. However, to find a way to make them equal the equation given is almost impossible (if not downright impossible)

Comment: @OscarLanzi that's one of the many problems with this question. I triple checked that I copied everything correct and it's indeed 3^xarcsinx

Answer (score 2):

A simple calculation show that $y=3^{x}\arcsin(x)$ is not a solution for the equation $(1-x^2)y^{\prime \prime}-xy^{\prime}=0$

Consider $$y^{\prime}=3^{x} \log (3) \arcsin(x)+\frac{3^x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
$$y^{\prime \prime}=\log(3)\left(  3^{x} \log (3) \arcsin(x)+\frac{3^x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \right)+3^{x} \log (3)\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}+\frac{x(3^x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$ and hence the first part is
$$y^{\prime \prime}(1-x^2)=3^{x}\log^2(x)\arcsin(x)(1-x^2)+3^{x}\log(3)(1-x^2)^{1/2}+3^{x}\log(3)(1-x^2)^{1/2}+\frac{x(3^x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$ and the second part $$xy^{\prime}=(3^x)x \log(3)\arcsin(x)+\frac{x(3^x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
Notice that the first part is different from the second, and hence $y$ can`t be a solution for the equation.

For find a solution, you can solve the differential equation $$(1-x^2)y^{\prime \prime}-xy^{\prime}=0$$ for $y$ by substitution, and if you do the correct calculation you should get as solution $$y=c_1\arcsin(x)+c_2$$ where $c_1,c_2\in \mathbb{R}$.